# Get json response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to get the status of loggedin user from the below code.

```
var responsePromise = $http.get("http://www.vbought.com/wrangleit/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username="+$scope.username+"&password="+$scope.password+"&callback=?");
                responsePromise.success(function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
                });
```

And here is what I get in the "data"

```
({"status":"error","error":"Invalid username and\/or password."})
```

I want to get the STATUS value. I can not get it with "data.status" or "data['status']". Is there any another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to get this page in browser, and I've got the:
?({"status":"error","error":"Invalid username and/or password."})

Then removed last '?', so now URL looks like 
http://www.vbought.com/wrangleit/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=%22+$scope.username+%22&password=%22+$scope.password+%22&callback=
And I've got:
{"status":"error","error":"Invalid username and/or password."}

Don't know what the server does, but it looks like it doesn't like the '?' at the end. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.parse](http://www.javascripture.com/JSON#parse) to convert the string to a JavaScript object with 'status' and 'error' properties. You should also remove the 'callback=?' part of the request. That will cause the result to be wrapped in '?()' since it is trying to call a function with the name you specified (in this case '?').  See [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for more information on the use of callback in requests.

```html
<script>
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', "http://www.vbought.com/wrangleit/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=foo&password=bar", /* async = */ false);
  request.send();
  var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  document.write('status = "' + response.status + '"');
</script>
```